# ImageCropper.Forms: How to get the stream & path value of the final cropped image?

Tags: xamarin.forms, path, stream

I am using [ImageCropper.Forms](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms) for cropping the image selected from the camera and gallery.

**My Code:**

```
    async void OpenCamera()
    {
        try
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
            //I need to open camera only here, no need of a pop up again.
            new ImageCropper()
            {
                PageTitle = "Test Title",
                AspectRatioX = 1,
                AspectRatioY = 1,
                CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
                SelectSourceTitle = "Select source",
                TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",
                PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library",
                Success = (imageFile) =>
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        profilephoto.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                    });
                }
            }.Show(this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CameraException:>" + ex);
        }
    }

async void Opengallery()
{
    try
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        //I need to open gallery only here, no need of a pop up again.
        new ImageCropper()
        {
            PageTitle = "Test Title",
            AspectRatioX = 1,
            AspectRatioY = 1,
            CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
            SelectSourceTitle = "Select source",
            TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",
            PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library",
            Success = (imageFile) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    profilephoto.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                    //var stream = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                    //imagefile = imageFile;
                });
            }
        }.Show(this);
    }
}
 
//Save image to gallery
private MediaFile _mediaFile;
public async void SaveProfile(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()), "\"file\"", $"\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri("Service URL"), content).Result;
}
```

I need to save the cropped image to the server, I was using [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) in my initial implementation, and using that plugin I get the selected image as a MediaFile. Using MediaFile I am able to save the picture to the server using its stream and path like below.

But after the cropping implementation, I don't know how to get the stream value and path of the final cropped image. So please suggest a solution for that issue. `SaveProfile` is an another function outside `OpenCamera()` and `Opengallery()`.

Comment: Please avoid putting tags in title when it is not necessary [Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as shown in the [docs](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms#usage), use a `Success` handler

```
new ImageCropper()
{
    Success = (imageFile) =>
    {
        // image file is the string path, do whatever you
        // need here
        var stream = File.Open(imageFile);
    }
}.Show(this);
```

where `imageFile` is a string containing the file path

Comment: Could you please explain more? I need stream value also

Comment: there are numerous existing questions that explain how to create a stream using a file path

Comment: see expanded example

Comment: your proposed edit shows that you actually want a **byte array**, not a stream.  If that's what you need, ImageCropper has a helper to do that.  See the docs: https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms#get-byte-from-image-file

Answer (score 1):

You could the plugin [FileUploaderPlugin](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FileUploaderPlugin) .

```
Success = (imageFile) =>
    {
       CrossFileUploader.Current.UploadFileAsync("<URL HERE>", new FilePathItem("<REQUEST FIELD NAME HERE>","<FILE PATH HERE>"), new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                   {"<HEADER KEY HERE>" , "<HEADER VALUE HERE>"}
                }
    );
    }
```